# How to get my elementary laptop to show my quad-core CPU info?

Tags: release-freya, cpu, laptop, conky

I have an elementary laptop that has an Intel Quad-Core i3-3217U CPU (1.80GHz) processor. I would like to get all four of my processor cores displayed in my Conky. Is there commands for certain info that I need or is it a straightforward thing that I'm overcomplicating? Also if anyone could let me know how to start Conky on boot I would be grateful. I am fairly new to Linux, so the more detailed and novice-friendly the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to tell you but 3217u is a dual core processor. You can see its specifications at:
[Intel i3 3217u](http://ark.intel.com/m/products/65697/intel-core-i3-3217u-processor-3m-cache-1_80-ghz#@product/specifications)

However you can add some variables to your .conkyrc to see information about your cores. For example, you can add:

```
${cpu cpuX}
```

With x=0 to see total CPU usage in percent, and X>=1 to see individual cores.

For more information about conky variables, you can see:

[Conky variables](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html)

To start conky on boot you can add it  in Configuration > Applications > Startup .

Comment: Thank you :) I always thought it was a dual core but, in system settings it displays 'Processor: Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz' which made me think otherwise. I'll have a look into what you wrote though!

Comment: System settings always show threads instead cores. 3217u has 4 threads.

Comment: You're welcome. You can voted my answer to help others.